# Libgdx getting screen size

Tags: libgdx, screen

I'm working on libgdx project. I basically recreate my game which I coded in xna to make it available for android. Here's the problem android has many screen resolutions, and I want to know how to get them.

i tried `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` or `getHeight()` but it gives me null pointer exceptions.

Comment: Are you calling that before or after you new up a LwjglApplication?

Comment: sorry i don't understand

Comment: The LwjglApplication is responsible for setting the static graphics property on the Gdx class, if you don't new up an instance of LwjglApplication you're going to have to set Gdx.graphics yourself.

Comment: listen, i don't know libgdx very good. let me show you the code

`public Player(Vector2 position){
  this.pos = position;
  speed = 500;
 }`

this is as you can see constructor for player class.

`Player p = new Player(new Vector2(224, 48));`

and i have this in main class after class opens.

i want to change that hardcoded numbers with screen width and height  and modify it with basic - or + operators.

Comment: What platform are you building for? Desktop, Android or HTML?

Comment: As said questions for android and also im testing it on desktop

Comment: Sorry, I missed it was for Android.
What does your launcher class for Android look like (this is the class that extends AndroidApplication). And for the Desktop; what does the main class in the Desktop project look like? Also, are you calling this on a thread different than the UI thread?

Comment: I haven't really changes anything in android activity i have set basic resolutions. As i said im really new to libgdx. I have read basic documentation but not much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20356/discussion-between-bornander-and-brsgamer).

Comment: Can you specify the exception ? `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` is static.

Answer (score 3):

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
camera.setToOrtho(false,800,400);
```

Above code will draw everything in your game on 800*400 virtual screen (in pixel) and fit, stretch, fill etc (see viewports ) on device's screen, independent of device screen size.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Orthographic-camera

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Answer (score 3):

once there's a valid screen loaded Gdx.graphics must have a valid width and height defined, i think you're just asking for something null that's not related

i.e. float[] size; size[0] = Gdx.graphics.getWidth(); ...

which it will give you a nice NPE

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to specify android screen fix size if you want you Libgdx project on all android Devices. 
I have test this. Just specify screen size that you can get from    Gdx.graphics.getWidth() and also for Height. 
You can give some fix value to Camera.. 
Test it on different android devices and this will work same on all.